# Ubuntu 22.04: Unable to stop systemd-resolved: it is relauched

Tags: 22.04, systemd-resolved

on ubuntu 22.04, i tried to stop and disable systemd-resolved:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved

sudo systemctl disable  systemd-resolved

sudo systemctl status  systemd-resolved

○ systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
```

but the process are still up:

```
ps auxw | grep resolved
systemd+  166263  0.0  0.0  23964 12648 ?        Ss   mai28   0:12 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
systemd+  166266  0.0  0.0  23932 12672 ?        Ss   mai28   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
systemd+  166271  0.0  0.0  23932 12636 ?        Ss   mai28   0:34 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
systemd+  166272  0.0  0.0  23932 12692 ?        Ss   mai28   0:03 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
```

even if i kill them:

```
sudo killall systemd-resolved
```

it comes back immediatly:

```
ps auxw | grep resolved
systemd+  253920  0.5  0.0  23964 12488 ?        Ss   15:04   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
systemd+  253923  0.6  0.0  23932 12788 ?        Ss   15:04   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
systemd+  253928  0.5  0.0  23932 12712 ?        Ss   15:04   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
systemd+  253929  0.5  0.0  23932 12692 ?        Ss   15:04   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
gquentin  253934  0.0  0.0  17880  2380 pts/1    S+   15:04   0:00 grep --color=auto resolved
```

what is the reason of that?

Regards,
Gaétan

Comment: What happens if you reboot after the service is disabled - does it still come up?

Comment: ok when rebooting it disappears. weird. thank you.